# Сотрировка списка списков по второму элементу

Tags: python, сортировка, list, список

Есть список:

```
[['A', 2], ['B', 3], ['C', 4], ['D', 3], ['E', 2], ['F', 1], ['G', 1]]
```

Нужно сделать сортировку, чтобы первый элемент (в отсортированном списке) был с максимальным вторым элементом исходного списка, и так далее по убыванию.
Например, в списке, что я задал выше, первый элемент будет `['C', 4]` , второй - `['B', 3]` и так далее...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

воспользуйтесь параметрами `key` и `reverse` функции [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
res = sorted(data, reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

результат:

```
In [393]: res
Out[393]: [['C', 4], ['B', 3], ['D', 3], ['A', 2], ['E', 2], ['F', 1], ['G', 1]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Используйте функцию `sort`, чтобы отсортировать текущий список. Либо функцию `sorted`, для получения нового отсортированного списка.

Для сортировки используется атрибут `key`, а чтобы порядок был по убыванию `reverse=True`.

*Кст, `key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])` делает сортировку по двум значениям -- сначала по `x[1]`, а после для одинаковых значений `x[1]` сортирует по `x[0]`*

Пример с `sort`:

```
items = [['A', 2], ['B', 3], ['C', 4], ['D', 3], ['E', 2], ['F', 1], ['G', 1]]

items.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(items)
# [['C', 4], ['B', 3], ['D', 3], ['A', 2], ['E', 2], ['F', 1], ['G', 1]]

items.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
print(items)
# [['C', 4], ['D', 3], ['B', 3], ['E', 2], ['A', 2], ['G', 1], ['F', 1]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Практические методы уже есть, что ж пусть будет учебный.

```
def quicksort(l):
    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []

    if len(l) > 1:
        p = l[0]
        for i in l:
            if i[1] < p[1]:
                less.append(i)
            elif i[1] == p[1]:
                equal.append(i)
            elif i[1] > p[1]:
                greater.append(i)
        return quicksort(less) + equal + quicksort(greater)
    else:
        return l

array = [['A', 2], ['B', 3], ['C', 4], ['D', 3], ['E', 2], ['F', 1], ['G', 1]]
print(quicksort(array))
```

Сортировка по возрастанию. А по убыванию можно например использовать `[::-1]` или `reversed`. А можно модифицировать алгоритм:

```
def quicksort(l):
    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []

    if len(l) > 1:
        p = l[0]
        for i in l:
            if i[1] < p[1]:
                less.append(i)
            elif i[1] == p[1]:
                equal.append(i)
            elif i[1] > p[1]:
                greater.append(i)
        return quicksort(greater) + equal + quicksort(less)
    else:
        return l

array = [['A', 2], ['B', 3], ['C', 4], ['D', 3], ['E', 2], ['F', 1], ['G', 1]]
print(quicksort(array))
```

В любом случае на практике [не пишете так](https://bash.im/quote/464236). Ну а если это что-то учебное — тогда это неплохо. Удачи!